# Fullscreen text area without JQuery

Tags: javascript

How to make fullscreen textarea without Jquery or any library?

```js
let el = document.getElementById('#t')

const fullScrenn = () => {
   //there way to do that . 
}
```

```html
<textarea id="el" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<button onclick="fullScrenn()">Full Screen</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Btw the `getElementById` doesn't work with the `#` hash character. Just remove it like this `document.getElementById('el')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
'use strict';
document.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#myTextarea').style.width="100vw";
  document.querySelector('#myTextarea').style.height="100vh";
});
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea" cols="20" rows="20"></textarea>
<button id="myButton">Full Size</button>
```

Just set the width and height of the `textarea` to `100vw` (the width of the screen) and `100vh` (the height of the screen).

Alternatively you could use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` instead of those values.

Comment: Thank everyone) Your help a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can change the css style to make fullscreen textarea

```js
var el = document.getElementById('el')

const fullScrenn = () => {
   el.style = "width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed;" 
}
```

```html
<textarea id="el" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<button onclick="fullScrenn()">Full Screen</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a css `class` with the follow properties.

```
.fullscreen{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:fixed;
}
```

When you **trigger** the click event handler, add `fullscreen` class to the **textarea** element.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('el')

const fullScrenn = () => {
   el.className+="fullscreen"; 
}
```

```css
.fullscreen{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="el" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<button onclick="fullScrenn()">Full Screen</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript:**

```js
document.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#myTextarea').style.width= window.innerWidth+"px";
  document.querySelector('#myTextarea').style.height= window.innerHeight+"px";
});
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea" cols="20" rows="20"></textarea>
<button id="myButton">Full Size</button>
```

**Javascript And Css:**

```js
document.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").className += " fullscreen";
});
```

```css
.fullscreen{ 
    width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea" cols="20" rows="20"></textarea>
<button id="myButton">Full Size</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Snippet here as well as other online IDE that run in an iframe (which is pretty much all of them) don't allow fullscreen code to work. So in order to see this demo to work, you'll need to copy n paste to a real site or you can do it locally as well.

This is using the [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), it's a true fullscreen

### Demo

*Not functioning due to SO security measures (no `allowfullscreen` on iframe)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <style>
    #t:-webkit-full-screen {
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>



  <textarea id="t" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

  <button id='btn'>Full Screen</button>




  <script>
    var el = document.getElementById('t');

    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
      fs(el);
    };

    var fsActive = function() {
      return !!(document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.fullscreenElement);
    };


    function fs(target) {
      if (!fsActive()) {

        if (target.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          target.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (target.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          target.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (target.requestFullscreen) {
          target.requestFullscreen();
        }

      } else {
        if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank everyone) Your help a lot